# Fixed side bar with slide out off canvas navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

Someone asked me how to make a slide out off canvas navigation menu a la [Lanyon](http://lanyon.getpoole.com/) from the Poole series for Jekyll. I originally learned how to make an off canvas navigation from [this Scotch.io tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/off-canvas-menus-with-css3-transitions-and-transforms), which uses CSS3 transforms.

I have two pens:

- [Here's one that utilizes the CSS3 transform method](http://codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/QjBwpB)
- [This one uses absolute positioning](http://codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/avjoaV)

The two pens are almost identical. In the first example, if you find the `aside` and change the position to `fixed`, it doesn't do anything useful. Upon further investigation, it looks like you can't set a fixed position to an element that's been transformed.

So, I just had to figure out some sort of hack to make it work, which I did by setting everything to `position: absolute` with varying degrees of `left`, and putting transitions on all the elements (the nav icon, the `main`, the `aside`).

However, where the CSS3 transition is smooth, the positioning hack is jagged. It's especially noticeable on mobile.

Anyway, I was curious as to what a more effective method to achieve the fixed slide out sidebar would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

off-canvas nav can be easy make with a little JQuery and some CSS.
In this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/tc0nxhLa/7/) you can see that.
I don't know why in JSFiddle and CODE SNIPPET i can't place the `transform: translateX(290px);` to the right class (see comments of CSS) but i test the full code on browser and it  run very well. I add some CSS for a "good" UI but you can easy edit it if you know basic CSS. I hope that can help you.

**EDIT:**

For keep the scroll active when NAV is open you have only to delet `overflow: hidden;` from `.m-nav-open` class

```js
$(function(){  
 $(".m-nav-opener").click(function(){
  if ($("body").hasClass("m-nav-open")){
   $("body").removeClass("m-nav-open");
  } else {
   $("body").addClass("m-nav-open");
  }
 });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
            transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
    text-rendering: optimizespeed;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.m-nav-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1001;
  width: 290px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2F2F2F;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  left: -290px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
          transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
}
.m-nav-open {
  /*transform: translateX(290px); use this on your code*/
}
.m-nav-open .m-nav-container {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(290px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(290px);
          transform: translateX(290px); /* cancel this on your code*/
}
.nav-mobile {
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-mobile ul {
  list-style: outside none none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin:0px;
}
.nav-mobile li {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid #292929;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}
.nav-mobile li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #292929;
}
.nav-mobile a {
  display: block;
  color: #919191;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif, Helvetica;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.0em;
}
.nav-mobile a:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #505050;
}
.m-nav-opener {
  border: medium none;
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  padding: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 3%;
  top: 24px;
  position: absolute;
}
.m-nav-opener:hover {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
.m-nav-opener:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
.m-nav-opener:active {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="m-nav-opener">OPEN</button>
<div class="m-nav-container">
<nav class="nav-mobile">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
<p style="height:2000px;">Hi</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! On your test, I added an element with height to create scroll. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsz1qk60/). `<p style="height:2000px;">Hi</p>` When you click to open the nav, it disables scroll. I'm trying to prevent that. Would you have any advice?

Comment: Sure, i prefer disable scroll when NAV is open but if you want you can easy keep the scroll. See update DEMO

Comment: Ah, excellent, thank you! I will work on implementing that with my design.

Comment: I also added [transform and transition to the button](http://jsfiddle.net/tc0nxhLa/8/)